# Php Ajax how insert data into two tables same time

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to insert data into two different tables. My problem is that it only inserts into one table the "pm_imbox",I am not familiar with ajax so is there anyway that i can do this using ajax ?

Here is my code

```
        <?php

    require_once"db.php";
    $to_username = $_POST['to_username'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to_userid = $_POST['to_userid'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $request_id = $_POST['request_id'];
    $from_username = $_POST['from_username'];
    $senddate = $_POST['senddate'];

    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_outbox(userid,username,to_userid,to_username,title,content,ReqID,senddate)VALUES('$userid','$from_username','$to_userid','$to_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_imbox(userid,username,from_id,from_username,title,content,ReqID,recieve_date)VALUES('$to_userid','to_username','$userid','$from_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

    $stmt->bindparam(':to_username', $to_username);
    $stmt->bindparam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindparam(':message', $message);
    $stmt->bindparam(':to_userid', $to_userid);
    $stmt->bindparam(':userid', $userid);
    $stmt->bindparam(':request_id', $request_id);
    $stmt->bindparam(':from_username', $from_username);
    $stmt->bindparam(':senddate', $senddate);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
      $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
      echo json_encode($res);
    }
    else {
      $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
      echo json_encode($error);
    }



     ?>
```

I am guessing it might be the  `$stmt->bindparam`, I do not know how to config them to link with the query
This is what i have done so far with my ajax JavaScript file.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

      function insertData() {
        var to_username=$("#to_username").val();
        var title=$("#title").val();
        var message=$("#message").val();
        var to_userid=$("#to_userid").val();
        var userid=$("#userid").val();
        var request_id=$("#request_id").val();
        var from_username=$("#from_username").val();
        var senddate=$("#senddate").val();


    // AJAX code to send data to php file.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "reply_process.php",
                data: {to_username:to_username,title:title,message:message,to_userid:to_userid,userid:userid,request_id:request_id,from_username:from_username,senddate:senddate},
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                 $("#message").html(data);
                $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
                },
                error: function(err) {
                alert(err);
                }
            });

    }

      </script>
```

Comment: Do you want to insert the same data to both of the tables?

Comment: Ajax is a way of sending a request to your server. From the perspective of this PHP script, the fact that it's called through Ajax is of zero imporance. It just gets a chunk of (post) data and has to deal with it. In fact, in many cases it's easier to test a script like this using a plain old HTML form, or using a testing tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: You prepare the first statement, and then prepare the second statement and store it in the same variable, `$stmt`. That variable from that point on only holds the seconds statement. The assignment doesn't magically transform $stmt into a list of statements to execute. Store them in separate variables, `$stmt1` and `$stmt2` (or more descriptive names) and call `->execute()` for each of them. You may want to read a little about transactions too, to make sure that if the second fails, the first is rolled back too (atomic operation).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has one variable `$stmt` which holds the query.
There are two lines which assign query string to the same variable `$stmt` and so the final query `$stmt` variable will be having is `pm_imbox` because it will replace the 1st assigned query for `pm_outbox`

Correct it and you will be good to go:

```
$stmt1 = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_outbox(userid,username,to_userid,to_username,title,content,ReqID,senddate)VALUES('$userid','$from_username','$to_userid','$to_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

$stmt1->bindparam(':to_username', $to_username);
$stmt1->bindparam(':title', $title);
$stmt1->bindparam(':message', $message);
$stmt1->bindparam(':to_userid', $to_userid);
$stmt1->bindparam(':userid', $userid);
$stmt1->bindparam(':request_id', $request_id);
$stmt1->bindparam(':from_username', $from_username);
$stmt1->bindparam(':senddate', $senddate);

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_imbox(userid,username,from_id,from_username,title,content,ReqID,recieve_date)VALUES('$to_userid','to_username','$userid','$from_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

$stmt->bindparam(':to_username', $to_username);
$stmt->bindparam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindparam(':message', $message);
$stmt->bindparam(':to_userid', $to_userid);
$stmt->bindparam(':userid', $userid);
$stmt->bindparam(':request_id', $request_id);
$stmt->bindparam(':from_username', $from_username);
$stmt->bindparam(':senddate', $senddate);

if($stmt1->execute() && $stmt->execute())  // This will execute both the queries.
{
    ....
    //further code
    ....
```

Comment: So if `$stmt->execute()` fails, you would display 'Not inserted'.. But `$stmt1` did execute earlier, so that was inserted..

Comment: Actually the main issue is, using the same `$stmt` variable. The `if` condition should be placed according to the need.

Comment: It's true that this solves the immediate problem of using the same variable But I mean that your code assumes that the statements either both succeed or both fail, which is not necessarily the case in a real life scenario, which is why you typically want to go a step further and apply a transaction here

Answer (score 0):

The second statement below overrides the first one, that's why only second one executes :

```
 $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_outbox(userid,username,to_userid,to_username,title,content,ReqID,senddate)VALUES('$userid','$from_username','$to_userid','$to_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

 $stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_imbox(userid,username,from_id,from_username,title,content,ReqID,recieve_date)VALUES('$to_userid','to_username','$userid','$from_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");
```

So, You if you need to execute both queries in one go, then change the logic as follows.

```
$stmt1 = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_outbox(userid,username,to_userid,to_username,title,content,ReqID,senddate)VALUES('$userid','$from_username','$to_userid','$to_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

$stmt2 = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_imbox(userid,username,from_id,from_username,title,content,ReqID,recieve_date)VALUES('$to_userid','to_username','$userid','$from_username','$title','$message','$request_id','$senddate')");

if($stmt1->execute() && $stmt1->execute()){
// do you stuff
}
```